# how to concat specific rows through a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

so, i have this situation:

there is a dataframe like this:

| Number | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | name 2 |
| 1002 | name2(pt1) |
| **NaN** | **name2(pt2)** |
| 1003 | name3 |
| 1004 | name4(pt1) |
| **NaN** | **name4(pt2)** |
| 1005 | name5 |

So, i need to concat the name (part1 and part2) together into junt one field and then drop the NaN rows but i have no clue how to do this because the rows do not follown a specific interval pattern

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) on a series based on the `notna` Number values.

Groups are created from:

```
df['Number'].notna().cumsum()
```

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    4
6    5
Name: Number, dtype: int32
```

Then aggregate taking the 'first' `Number` (since first value is guaranteed to be notna) and doing some operation to combine `Descriptions` like `join`:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(df['Number'].notna().cumsum(), as_index=False)
        .aggregate({'Number': 'first', 'Description': ''.join})
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    Number           Description
0  10001.0                name 2
1   1002.0  name2(pt1)name2(pt2)
2   1003.0                 name3
3   1004.0  name4(pt1)name4(pt2)
4   1005.0                 name5
```

Or comma separated `join`:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(df['Number'].notna().cumsum(), as_index=False)
        .aggregate({'Number': 'first', 'Description': ','.join})
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    Number            Description
0  10001.0                 name 2
1   1002.0  name2(pt1),name2(pt2)
2   1003.0                  name3
3   1004.0  name4(pt1),name4(pt2)
4   1005.0                  name5
```

Or as `list`:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(df['Number'].notna().cumsum(), as_index=False)
        .aggregate({'Number': 'first', 'Description': list})
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    Number               Description
0  10001.0                  [name 2]
1   1002.0  [name2(pt1), name2(pt2)]
2   1003.0                   [name3]
3   1004.0  [name4(pt1), name4(pt2)]
4   1005.0                   [name5]
```